# A norm one projection

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be Hilbert space and $\mathfrak{B(}\mathcal{H}\mathcal{)}$ of all bounded linear operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a maximal commutative sub-algebra of $\mathfrak{B(}\mathcal{H)}$.

1. Is there an explicit formula a conditional expectation (a norm one projection) $\pi:\mathfrak{B(}\mathcal{H}\mathcal{)\longrightarrow A}$?
2. If Yes, I would be greatful if you could please give me it.
   \end{enumerate}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frege, maximal abelian subalgebras of von Neumann algebras are von Neumann algebras, hence are of the form $L_\infty(\mu)$ for some measure $\mu$. See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110461/direct-proof-of-injectivity-of-l-infty) of Bill Johnson to see a neat way to produce a projection. The problem is that in general masas of $\mathscr{B}(\mathcal{H})$ are elusive, so are the corresponding norm-one projections.

In some particular cases, however, this is not difficult. For instance, when $\mathcal{H}=\ell_2$ and you regard operators on $\mathcal{H}$ as matrices with respect to the canonical basis, you just chop off the diagonal to produce a projection.

Comment: In their famous 1959 paper where they introduce the Kadison-Singer problem (recently solved), R.V. Kadison and I.M. Singer prove that, in the case of $\ell^2$, taking the diagonal is the only projection onto the corresponding MASA of diagonal operators; and that for $L^2[0,1]$ there are at least two projections on the MASA $L^\infty [0,1]$; see 
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2372748?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103125859707

Comment: If there is a norm one projection, then $\cal A$ has to be self-adjoint, because unital norm one maps are automatically positive. Every self-adoint maximal abelian subalgebra ${\cal A}\subset{\cal B}(H)$ is unitarily equivalent to $L^\infty(X,\mu)\subset{\cal B}(L^2(X,\mu))$.