# Both $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ belong to $\mathcal{B}_1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am looking for a resource or some hints on why the two normed spaces $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ belong to the family $\mathcal{B}_1$, that is,
they are of the family of Banach spaces $X$ such that for any Banach space $X'$ containing $X$ there is a projection $P$ from $X'$ to $X$ such that $\lVert P\rVert\leq 1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470869/equivalent-definitions-of-injective-banach-spaces

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110461/direct-proof-of-injectivity-of-l-infty

Answer (score 2):

I think the general fact is that $\mathcal{B}_1$ consists of precisely the Banach spaces (isometrically isomorphic to) the spaces $C(X)$ for $X$ extremally disconnected and compact. In particular, every $L^\infty$ space will belong to $\mathcal{B}_1$. See Projection constants and spaces of continuous functions by Isbell and Semadeni for references.